# generate DDL from JPA annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, jpa

I'm trying to generate a DDL from a set of JPA-annotated classes using the [hbm2ddl goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html) of the hibernate3-maven-plugin. I've configured the following in my pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hibernate-create-schema</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                                <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                            <persistenceunit>bm-domain</persistenceunit>
                            <outputfilename>create.sql</outputfilename>
                            <drop>false</drop>
                            <create>true</create>
                            <export>false</export>
                            <format>true</format>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My persistence.xml contains just the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="bm-domain" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">   
</persistence-unit>
```

And I've added a database.properties file to the classpath that specifies:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

When I run `mvn install` I get the error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could
>   not determine type for: java.util.Set,
>   at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(compatibleAnnualEarnings)]

which seems to refer to the following properties of the User class

```
Set<AnnualEarnings> compatibleAnnualEarnings;   

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
AnnualEarnings annualEarnings;
```

the `AnnualEarnings` class is in a sub-package of the User class' package and is defined thus:

```
public enum AnnualEarnings implements Serializable{
    GROUP_1, GROUP_2, GROUP_3, GROUP_4, GROUP_5, GROUP_6, GROUP_7;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you annotate your `Set<AnnualEarnings>` with an `@ElementCollection`?

This might be helpful as well: [Persisting set of Enums in a many-to-many unidirectional mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3152787/363573)

Comment: The meaningful information from the link here is dead. Here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3152787/363573