# How to properly map collection of enums in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, mapping

I have an entity which references a list of type enum. The list is stored in the database as following:

```
userName    role
-----------------------
user0001    role1
user0001    role2
user0001    role3
user0002    role1
```

The corresponding java class is roughly like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserTable")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "User_Roles")
    @Column(name = "role")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152787/persisting-set-of-enums-in-a-many-to-many-unidirectional-mapping) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416208/jpa-map-collection-of-enums) question for the mapping. Yet I have two issues. First issue is that the `userName` is not the PK in my `UserTable` and as far as I know, hibernate does join on the PK.

The second issue is this error with the current setup:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role:
>   com.project.Common.User.roles, could not initialize
>   proxy - no Session

This error shall be fixed by `EAGER` loading, but as I tried that one, I got the following error at startup:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to register multiple SQL
>   table aliases [roles1_, roles2_, etc] against query space
>   uid [< gen:1>]

**What do I need to change in order for this mapping to work?**

---

Please note that I wouldn't like to perform any database changes if that is in any way possible.

Also I do think that I would actually have to go with `FetchType.EAGER`, as I for now only query the database once and would need to get roles as well for later usage. Of course I could also change the way my application handles this and query the roles again when I need them explicitly, tho I am not sure if that way would be better.

Comment: Is there another resolution without Eager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a not so nice workaround. First of all, I annotated the `List<Role> roles;` as following:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)
@JoinTable(name = "User_Roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userName"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "role")
private List<Role> roles;
```

My `Role` enum does not have any annotations.

This setup would normally result in the `LazyInitializationException`, which I worked around by adding a `System.out.println(user);` as this does access the `roles` list (replacing it with a `getRoles()` resulted in the same exception) directly after fetching the user.

As you can guess, this solution is not really fine/acceptible at all. As long as I don't find a better solution (most probably eager-loading), I will roll with this one.

---

**UPDATE**

I actually got it solved. It works now with `eager-loading`. In fact, the setup remained as posted above in the answer. The `IllegalStateException` I mentioned in the question, is actually caused by the bug [HHH-12594](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12594). I simply removed `hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size` from my configuration and it then worked as intended.