# How to store enum data as Array List in a database using Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

> I have an enum class that contain multiple data ,I want to store that
> enum data as list in database. for example Developer table it contain
> technology column ,that column store enum data, Suppose one user want
> to store Developer1 working on many technologies like java , Kotllin ,
> .Net etc these technologies are belongs from enum class , How to store
> .
> Same as I have a Subject enum class that contain multiple subject name
> ,When I Register a new teacher then I want to store how many subjects
> teacher know ,If he know multiple subjects that present in our enum
> class list then store the subjects id which known by the teacher.But I
> am not able to store multiple data in a single column in subjectId ,It
> store only one Data in SubjectId column,If I pass multiple data in
> subjectId column in postman it throws error 400
> teacherEntity class

```
package com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.entity

import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum.Subject
import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum.University
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class Teacher(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val nameOfTeacher:String="",
    val price:Long=-1,
    val subject:Int = Subject.MATH.type,//List<Int> = listOf(Subject.MATH.type)
    val university:Int=University.OTHER.type
)
```

> Subject enum class

```
package com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum

enum class Subject(val type:Int) {
    MATH(1),
    PHYSIC(2),
    ACCOUNTING(3),
    ZOOLOGY(4),
    BIOLOGY(5),
    PROGRAMMING(6),
    STATICS(7),
    CHEMISTRY(8),
    HISTORY(9)
}
```

> ReqTeacher Model class

```
package com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.model.request

import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum.Subject import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum.University

data class ReqTeacher(
    val nameOfTeacher:String="",
    val price:Long=-1,
    val subject:Int= Subject.MATH.type,
    val university:Int= University.OTHER.type, )
```

> Response Teacher Model class

```
package com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.model.response

import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum.Subject
import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.enum.University

data class ResTeacher(
    val nameOfTeacher:String="",
    val price:Long=-1,
    val subject:Int= Subject.MATH.type,
    val university:Int= University.OTHER.type,
)
```

> Teacher controller class

```
package com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.controller

import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.entity.Teacher
import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.model.request.ReqTeacher
import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.model.response.ResTeacher
import com.nilmani.jpqlprojectexample.repository.TeacherRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/teachTest")
class TeacherController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var teachRopo:TeacherRepository

    @PostMapping("/add")
    fun addTeacher(@ModelAttribute request:ReqTeacher):ResponseEntity<*>{
//        val newTeacher = teachRopo.findById(request.)
        var newTeacher = Teacher(
            nameOfTeacher = request.nameOfTeacher,
            price = request.price,
            subject = request.subject,
            university = request.university,
        )
        val saveTeacher = teachRopo.save(newTeacher)
        val respTeacher = ResTeacher(
            saveTeacher.nameOfTeacher,
            saveTeacher.price,
            saveTeacher.subject,
            saveTeacher.university
        )
        return ResponseEntity(respTeacher,HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

> I want to store multiple data or single data in SubjectId column of a
> particular teacherId,But My code store only one data for a particular
> teacherId

Answer (score 0):

You should have a new table (Entity) that represents the 1-to-many relationship between Teacher and Subject, e.g. `teacher_subject`. This is the proper approach. If you attempt to store the subjects as space/comma-separated values in a single cell, e.g. "math, physics, biology" that would be bad practice.

Comment: Subject is not a entity class it just an enum class how it possible to establish one to many relation between Teacher entity class and Subject enum class

Comment: I found this answer on SO that uses `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153172/9698467